# MSIX install failing "This app package is not supported for installation by App Installer because it uses certain restricted capabilities"

Tags: msix

We have a .NET application that we package and distribute to our customers as an MSIX. The package is signed by us using a Sertico code signing certificate.

The MSIX works for most customers. However, we have run into an issue where it is failing for a customer, showing the error:

```
This app package is not supported for installation by App Installer because it uses certain restricted capabilities.
```

There are no details about the restricted capabilities that are causing the problem or why this works for every other customer. The customer can install the package using Powershell and that works fine.

The customer is running Windows 10 21H1. They don't have developer mode enabled, but neither do our other customers who are able to install.

What might be causing this issue, and how can we resolve it?